# text index required for $text query error while search text in MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB and I created an index on a filed as below:

```
var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions();
var indexKeys = Builders<Book>.IndexKeys.Ascending(book=> book.title);
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<Book>(indexKeys, indexOptions);
collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(indexModel);
```

After that I want to search a text in the collection as below:

```
var filter = Builders<Book>.Filter.Text(textToSearch);
var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList(); // Error occurs here
```

But I get "Command find failed: text index required for $text query." error on the last line.

Update:

I created the index manually in `mongo` command line interface:

```
db.Book.createIndex({title:1})
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create [Text Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) for [Text operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) to work, as the exception mention, you don't have a text index, because you are creating single field index, please read more about [indexes type in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#index-types)

To fix this in your code, you will have to replace this

```
var indexKeys = Builders<Book>.IndexKeys.Ascending(book=> book.title);
```

with this

```
var indexKeys = Builders<Book>.IndexKeys.Text(book=> book.title);
```

also it is good to know how to create this index via mongoshell

```
db.Book.createIndex({title:"text"})
```